# node mysql inserting current date

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

[mysql node](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) docs give an example of how to escape and do neat things. I am unable to figure out how to insert the current time using this approach.

```
var post  = {id: 1, createdDate: 'NOW()'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
});
// Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'createdDate' at row 1
```

Comment: There is issue https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/701...

Comment: @Alexander Thanks. Using custom formats seems complicated, I was hoping for an easier solution :-) I guess, I'll have to avoid using objects/arrays as data in the `connection.query` and escape them directly as individual variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy workaround if you do not want to use custom formats would be to generate date on server-side using `new Date()` :

```
var post = {
    id: 1,
    createdDate: new Date()
};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {});
```

But keep in mind you can have small delay because of server/network lag.